# What is the meaning of the "Missing Index Impact %" in a SQL Server 2008 execution plan?

Tags: sql-server

I was just examining an estimated execution plan in SSMS. I noticed that a query had query cost of 99% (relative to the batch). I then examined the plan displayed below. That cost was almost entirely coming from a "Clustered Index Delete" on table A. However, the Missing Index recommendation is for Table B. And the Missing Index Impact is said to be 95%.

The query is a `DELETE` statement (obviously) which relies on a nested loops `INNER JOIN` with `TableB`. If nearly all the cost according to the plan is coming from the `DELETE` operation, why would the index suggestion be on Table B which -- even though it was a scan -- had a cost of only 0%? Is the impact of 95% an impact against the neglible cost of the scan (listed as on 0%) and not the overall cost of the query (said to be nearly ALL of the batch)?

Please explain IMPACT if possible. Here is the plan:
[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Can you post the query and possibly the plan. Otherwise I'm just kind of taking a stab in the dark on this.

Comment: Query plan is posted. I didnt think it would show very well, but it is somewhat legible. Thanks so for the help.

Comment: Wait you're deleting out of a #table?

Comment: I didnt write this. There is a whole lot wrong with where this little gem came from. I cant provide the query due to confidentiality. Let me see if I can anonymize it...

Comment: The good news is if you apply that index and regenerate the query plan you'll find out exactly what difference it will make.

Comment: What are the `MissingIndex` details in the XML for that statement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is query 27 in the batch.

Probably the impact it is showing you actually belongs to an entirely different statement (1-26).

This seems to be a problem with the way that the impacts are displayed for **estimated** plans in SSMS.

The two batches below contain the same two statements with the order reversed. Notice in the first case it claims *both* statements would be helped equally with an impact of `99.38` and in the second `49.9818`.

So it is showing the estimated impact for the **first** instance encountered of that missing index - Not the one that actually relates to the statement.

I don't see this issue in the actual execution plans and the correct impact is actually shown in the plan XML next to each statement even in the estimated plan.

I've added a Connect item report about this issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/812880/missing-index-impact-displayed-incorrectly-for-multi-statement-estimated-plans). (Though possibly you have encountered another issue as 10% impact seems to be the cut off point for the missing index details being included in the plan and it is difficult to see how that would be possible for the same reasons as described in the question)

Example Data

```
CREATE TABLE T1
  (
     X INT,
     Y CHAR(8000)
  )

INSERT INTO T1
            (X)
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@spid)
FROM   sys.all_objects o1,
       sys.all_objects o2
```

Batch 1

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE X = -1

SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE X = -1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM T1
```

[image]

Batch 2

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE X = -1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM T1

SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE X = -1
```

[image]

The XML for the first plan (heavily truncated) is below, showing that the correct information is in the plan itself.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML>
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1">
          <QueryPlan>
            <MissingIndexes>
              <MissingIndexGroup Impact="99.938">
                <MissingIndex Database="[tempdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T1]">
                  <ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY">
                    <Column Name="[X]" ColumnId="1" />
                  </ColumnGroup>
                </MissingIndex>
              </MissingIndexGroup>
            </MissingIndexes>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="2">
          <QueryPlan>
           <MissingIndexes>
              <MissingIndexGroup Impact="49.9818">
                <MissingIndex Database="[tempdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T1]">
                  <ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY">
                    <Column Name="[X]" ColumnId="1" />
                  </ColumnGroup>
                </MissingIndex>
              </MissingIndexGroup>
            </MissingIndexes>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: I've just tried your example with SQL Server 2016 and it shows two different impacts for the two queries. So it seems to me that the issue is now solved on newer versions.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that interpretation of **missing impact %** is identical or similar with that of `avg_user_impact` column from [sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) system view then **missing impact %** represents (more or less):

> Average percentage benefit that user queries could experience if this
>   missing index group was implemented. The value means that the query
>   cost would on average drop by this percentage if this missing index
>   group was implemented.

Comment: I see that. It seems the that this value mean that "query cost" would drop by that percentage. So then why would an index on table B cause a "clustered index delete on table A" to drop? The delete operation is the only part of the query plan that has any cost at all - 99%! Everything else is 0%. Doesn't make sense...

Comment: Except they are deleting from a temporary table so there can't be any FKs or triggers in play. I can't reproduce the scenario in the OP at all. If I add unrelated expensive operators to the query the impact figure drops down so it is definitely based on the overall plan cost. But difficult to see how that possibly squares with the example here.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the information everyone. Martin Smith I believe did find a bug as a result of this though I am not sure if it the same bug as what I am seeing.  In fact I am not sure if my issue is a bug or by design. Let me elaborate on some new observations:

In looking through this rather large execution plan (62 queries), I noticed the the Missing Index recommendation (and respective Impact %) that i mentioned in the original question is listed on nearly every query in the 62 query batch. Oddly, many of these queries do not even call the table the index is recommended for!  After observing this, I opened the XML and searched the element 'MissingIndexes' which showed about 10 different indexes missing all with varying Impact %'s, naturally.  Why the execution plan does not show this visually and instead shows just one Missing Indezx, I do not know. I presume it is either 1) a bug or 2) it only shows the missing index with the HIGHEST impact % - which is the one I see  riddled throughout my entire plan.

A suggestion if you are experiencing this too: Get comfortable with the XML over the visual execution plan. Search the xml element 'MissingIndexes' and match that up with the statements to get proper results.

I also read from Microsoft http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345524(v=sql.105).aspx
that the missing index stats come from a group of DMVs.  If the Impact % is in fact from these DMVs, then I would also presume that Impact % is based on MUCH MUCH more than just the Query/Statement in the execution plan were the index is recommended. So take it with a grain of salt, and use them wisely based your own knowledge of your database.

I am going to leave this opened-ended and not mark anything as an "answer" just yet. Feel free to chime in folks!

Thanks again.

Comment: I think you're right. If I add `SELECT * FROM sys.objects` to the batch in my answer I see the completely redundant missing index suggestion there too. Looks like it just takes the first missing index and plasters it on all plans.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so let me see if I can clarify here.

There will still be costs to those other operations the 0% is because the `DELETE` on a loop is taking the vast majority of of your processor and IO time. That doesn't however mean those other operations don't have processor/memory/IO costs that can be improved on this query by adding that index. Especially if you are doing a loop essentially your mapping to tableB for one record then deleting out of tableA over and over. Therefore having an index that makes it easier to match those rows will speed up your delete.

Comment: Zane, thank you. I posted the query plan to the question. I see what you are saying about the loop. I thought the looping was already completed by the time the plan moves on to the actual delete. Perhaps I dont understand this process (I will read up on it). I still find it odd that the 100% cost on the "delete" would receive the so-called "impact %" of 95%. If the index improved the looping, then I would think we would see higher cost on those operations,not 0%, in this plan. Perhaps the DELETE is so darn inefficient that we can hardly see IO (relative to the DELETE) expressed as a percent.